# Flutter app does not show any content on ios simulator

Tags: ios, flutter, ios-simulator, flutter-ios

I recently tried ios simulator to test my flutter app but for an unknown reason the app does not display any widgets and displays a white screen.

[image]

Comment: Not sure how to help without seeing any code

Comment: I tried the `helloWorld` flutter app to make things easier and I still faced the same issue.